# Table made from list (<ul>,<li>), how to select a row? (:nth-child())?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, html-lists, jquery

I made a table out of a simple list structure:

```
<html>
    <body>
      <ul id="Column:0">
        <li id="Row:0></li>
        <li id="Row:1></li>
        <li id="Row:2></li>
        <li id="Row:3></li>
        <li id="Row:4></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="Column:1">
        <li id="Row:0></li>
        <li id="Row:1></li>
        <li id="Row:2></li>
        <li id="Row:3></li>
        <li id="Row:4></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="Column:2">
        <li id="Row:0></li>
        <li id="Row:1></li>
        <li id="Row:2></li>
        <li id="Row:3></li>
        <li id="Row:4></li>
      </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to add a simple .mouseover() to every row, for e.g. changing the color of a row, when hovered. And this is what I figured out, so far:

```js
for (var i = 2;  i <= _totalRows; i++) {
    var row = $('#TimeTable ul li:nth-child(' + i + ')')
    row.each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(evt) {
            var $target = $(evt.target);
            console.log($target.nodeName)
            if (evt.target.nodeName == 'DIV') {
                console.log(evt.parent('li'));
            }
        }); //end $(this).click(fn)
    }); // end each(fn)
}
```

I get a set of all `<li>` objects matching to :nth-child(i) where `i` is the rows number.

```js
var row = $('#TimeTable ul li:nth-child(' + i + ')')
```

Now I just iter this set through to add a .click(fn) to every `<li>`.
This works fine. Every cell has it's .click(fn) attached to it.
But the following, what to do on a click, is where I'm stuck for several hours now:

```js
var $target = $(evt.target);
console.log($target.nodeName)
if (evt.target.nodeName == 'DIV') {
    console.log(evt.parent('li'));
}
```

I simply don't get it to run.
You can actually ignore this gibberish, as it's just the last of several things I already tried here.

What I'm trying to do is simply select every `<li>` with an id='Row:X' and manipulate its CSS. The best I yet had was, that I can click a cell, but no matter in what row this cell is, the last one gets colored. I remember having used `i` as the row-index, when that happened, so I might miss some understanding of event-handling here, too.

Comment: Those are real ID's or just for example?

Comment: ID's must be unique.

Comment: If you have tabular data, why not just use a table?

Comment: Echoing @KevinB, tables aren't evil. Using tables for layout is evil. Tables for data is appropriate.

Comment: Use `class="row1 col2"` in your `<li>`s; now you will be able to select everything in row1 with `$("li.row1")`, and everything in col2 with `$("li.col2")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class name for duplicate groups of elements not an ID. If you give row one a class of "Row1" the selector is simply:

```
$('.Row1')
```

Then:

```
$('#TimeTable li').removeClass('highlight');
$('.Row1').addClass('highlight');
```

Comment: This is, what I'm gonna do. Thanks Diodeus! :D.
I forgot to tell, that there is one `<div>` in every `<li>`, because I want every 'cell' to be replaceable by another `<div>`, that's dragged'n'dropped from kind of a menu.
These `<div>`s have the unique IDs. This is my first thing in jQuery, so I simply screwed up some logic behind all of this. Yay, me just learned something ;D

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to change the color on mouseover:

```
$('#TimeTable ul li').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('background','red');
});

$('#TimeTable ul li').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('background','green');
});
```

Comment: This would color ALL ´<li>´, doesn't it?

Comment: only the `<li>` inside `#TimeTable ul` you had your mouse over

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your ID's like so: C1R1 (Column1Row1) and so on
2. JQuery read/google up "jquery each"
3. JQuery read/google up "jquery bind click"
4. JQuery read/google up "jquery attr" and "JQuery val()"

This will give you the knowledge to write your own and most importantly understand it better. You will want to achieve the following (your close but no for loop required):

A list which JQuery attaches a click event handler to each LI, and then when the click happens the ID can be retrieved.

PS. There's a time and place for tables, they 9/10 times nearly always better for displaying data than CSS is. If you have a complex multi column row and want fiexed hights and no JS to fix things or do anything smart you can have a table and css :Hover on TR for stying mouse over and out etc. Heights are also constant.

PS. PS. If your data is dynamic and coming from a database and the whole row is an ID from the database I tend to avoid using the html ID attribute for this and make my own. You can retrieve this via attr("myattribute");

NOTE ON CSS and IDS:
Standard practice for ID's are to be used once on a page.
Class for repeatable content

Good luck.

Comment: @downvoter: please include reasons of downvote. The first suggestion is actually quite good, even though classes are better.

Comment: That was me, the answer was a lot shorter back then. I downvoted because it was a reading list of suggestions instead of answering the question.